# Index based on another index

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

Assume a mysql table with columns A, B, C, ... .

There are one composite index based on columns A+B+C. Combination of values A, B and C is unique, so this index forms the primary key.

Now, a second index is need. There are two possibilities for this one: a) A+B+D+E; b) D+E.

I wonder which one of the previous options for the second index is better. Any hint is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you gave no details of what you want to accomplish to base any hints on, I can tell you only the generic stuff:

If it is InnoDB then each secondary key contains the primary key values to find the right rows, so `(a,b,d,e)` is extended to `(a,b,d,e,c)` and `(d,e)` to `(d,e,a,b,c)` - as you can see, the columns indexed are the same but the order is not, and order of columns in multicolumn index is as important as the actual columns so those two are quite different in their effects.

If it is MyISAM, then the extension does not apply, each index references the row by a pointer to heap, so the indexes are totally different.

There is no universal notion of "better", it depends on what do you need the indexes for. Query speedup? Or are they supposed to be unique?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very interesting the point about keys automatically added. In addiiton, searching for information, I've found that the option of indexes (a,b,c) and (d,e) will solve a query using mysql "index merge". The queries will be of form "A=... AND B=... AND C=..." or "A=.... AND B=.... AND D=... AND E IN (...)".

Comment: Index merge is often the only possible index optimization for queries with OR. I mostly rewrite such queries to UNION as each part can then use the proper index even in cases where merge is not good enough. If there is index merge used for AND (intersection of indexes), then one combined index would be probably better. Afaik there was a problem in some older mysql versions where optimizer did not know how to use the "extending" columns on the index, so it was better to explicitly name the needed primary key columns in some cases.